# React: Componentdidupdate, Unable to access object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to access the value from a object key.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps !== this.props) {
            console.log("component did update in top menu", this.props.topmenudata[0])
            this.setState({
            });
        }
    }
```

In the above method i have passed some data to my child component through props and it is accessed through .topmenudata

when i console.log(this.props.topmenudata[0]), i get the following object

```
{baudrate: "1200", databits: "7", parity: "even", stopbits: "1"}
```

when i console.log(this.props.topmenudata), i get the following object

```
0: {baudrate: "1200", databits: "7", parity: "even", stopbits: "1"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

yet, when i try to get the value of baudrate from the object, through

```
console.log(this.props.topmenudata[0]["baudrate"])
```

i get the following returned

```
Cannot read property 'baudrate' of undefined
```

i have checked the type of data i am getting through

```
typeof(this.props.topmenudata[0])
```

and it shows that i am definitely getting an object

what am i missing here? is there something im missing in the componentdidupdate method?

Comment: Did you try this.props.topmenudata[0].baudrate ??

Comment: @Riddhi yes it returns cannot read property baudrate of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `console.log` inside a check that your object exists. It is likely that the first time `componentDidUpdate` is called, `topmenudata` is an empty list. Then in some future update, the list is populated and you get the valid data you see in your first `console.log`. In your example where you try and get `baudrate`, you never get to the future `componentDidUpdate` calls because the first one produces an execution-breaking error.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.topmenudata && this.props.topmenudata.length > 0) {
        console.log(this.props.topmenudata[0]);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

And this isn't part of your question, but you'll soon come across another issue with your code where your componentDidUpdate code will trigger every time your component updates, and not just when the props are different.

This is because the comparison you do in `prevProps !== this.props` will always evaluate to `true` because you are comparing object references. In Javascript, `{} === {}` is `false`.

You instead want to check the equality of two primitive types (like `strings` or `numbers`) from within your `prevProps` and `this.props`, where you only want your code to run if they update. Something like:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.topmenudata && this.props.topmenudata.length > 0) {
        let propsHaveChanged = false;
        this.props.topmenudata.forEach((serialInfo, index) => {
            if (!prevProps.topmenudata[index]) return;

            if (prevProps.topmenudata[index].baudrate !== serialInfo.baudrate) {
                propsHaveChanged = true;
            }
        });

        if (propsHaveChanged) {
            // run my code
        }
    }
}
```

Though this get's pretty complex pretty quickly, so if you're not confident, I'd recommend you look into pre-built deep-compare functions like the ones provided by underscore.js or lodash.js.

[Further reading on deep compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: @Dustyik looks like you may have an issue with object comparison in the near future, you may wish to check my edit

Comment: will do!!!! once again thanks so much for the help!! its greatly appreciated :)